# What should a simple integration test look like with Enzyme and useContext hook?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, integration-testing, enzyme

Help write a simple integration test for a component in React (the component uses the useContext hook). The test should verify that buttons were pressed and handlers called  (it's my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-violet-n11hu).

The code of the component that validates the test:

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import {StoreContext} from "../../reducer/context";
import moment from "moment";

import Delay from "../delay/delay";

let queue = Promise.resolve();

const Interface = () => {
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(StoreContext);

    const handleLogSet = e => {
        const timeout = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute("data-delay"), 10);
        const timePress = moment().format("LTS");
        queue = queue.then(() => Delay(timeout, timePress)).then(res => dispatch({
            type: "SET_LOG", payload: "\n" + res
        }));
    };

    const handleReset = () => {
        dispatch({type: "RESET"});
    };
    return (
        <div className="block">
            <button className="btn" data-delay="1" onClick={handleLogSet}>Кнопка 1</button>
            <button className="btn" data-delay="2" onClick={handleLogSet}>Кнопка 2</button>
            <button className="btn" data-delay="3" onClick={handleLogSet}>Кнопка 3</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={handleReset}>Reset</button>
            <textarea value={state.join("")} readOnly={true}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Interface;
```

Tried different test options, but none work. I tried, for example, like this:

```
import {configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Interface from "./interface";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "../../reducer/context";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const { state } = useContext(StoreContext);

it(`Click by button calls callback`, () => {
    const handleLogSet = jest.fn();

    const component = shallow(<Interface
        state={state}
    />);

    component.find(`.button`).simulate(`click`);
    expect(handleLogSet).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Various errors were issued, including the following: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component".

I would be very grateful for an example of a working code and a brief explanation. Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So everything was simple enough. It is worth noting that when testing components that use useContext using the shallow method of the Enzyme library, there are recognized difficulties. So far, it has not been possible to solve them directly.

The first thing to do is create a custom hook. You can do it like this:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

export const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);
const AppContext = React.createContext();

export default AppContext;
```

This is done in order not to use useContext directly in the component under test.

The e2e test itself looks something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {configure, shallow} from "enzyme";
import * as AppContext from "../../reducer/context";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import Interface from "./interface";

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

it(`Click by Set and Reset buttons calls callback`, () => {
    const contextValues = {state: ["Mock state"]};
    const handleReset = jest.fn();
    const handleLogSet = jest.fn();

    jest
        .spyOn(AppContext, "useAppContext")
        .mockImplementation(() => contextValues);
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <Interface
            onReset={handleReset}
            onLogSet={handleLogSet}
        />
    );
    wrapper.find(`.block__btn--reset`).simulate(`click`);
    expect(handleReset).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    wrapper.find(`.block__btn--set`).forEach(item => {
        item.simulate(`click`);
        expect(handleReset).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Thus, we mimic the implementation of our custom code and pass this value to the context object.

Comment: I get an error - Cannot spy the `AppContext` property because it is not a function;